# How do closures create memory leaks?

Tags: javascript

I was reviewing the slides in this presentation: http://slid.es/gruizdevilla/memory

and on one of the slides, this code is presented with the suggestion that it creates a memory leak:

```
var a = function () { 
   var smallStr = 'x',
   largeStr = new Array(1000000).join('x'); 

   return function (n) { 
        eval(''); //maintains reference to largeStr
        return smallStr; 
   }; 
}();
```

> Closures can be another source of memory leaks. Understand what references are retained in the closure.
>
> And remember: eval is evil

Can someone explain the issue here?

Comment: I don't believe that is a memory leak as defined by the same presentation (which said a leak is "when a program repeatedly fails to return memory that it has obtained for temporary use"), because it's not happening repeatedly. But `largeStr` will be tying up a chunk of memory until `a` goes out of scope. Also `eval()` isn't evil, it's just almost always the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Especially here, where `eval` seems to be used to prevent static code analysis which would allow the garbage collector to collect `largeStr` even when a reference to the returned function is alive.

Comment: @MedicineMan: Did you "*understand what references are retained in the closure*" or not?

Comment: @Bergi - So in this case `eval()` is the _right_ tool for the job, if the job is to deliberately tie-up memory. (As long as people understand that the lesson is "be careful with closures", not "`eval()` always ties up memory".)

Comment: @nnnnnn: Which is, I fear, what many people would do. It should better be replaced by something like `if (false) return largeStr;`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If instead of returning a function that does

```
    eval('');
```

you returned one that passes its argument

```
    eval(n);
```

then someone could call `a('largeStr')` to get the array, so the JavaScript interpreter cannot garbage collect the array.

Interpreters could realize that

```
eval('');
```

is equivalent to

```
;
```

but most are not smart enough to do that, so as soon as they see `eval` they stop allowing GC of closed-over variables as long as the closure is reachable.

---

The memory leak arises when `eval` can't effectively access closed-over variables because of the nature of its input:

```
eval('x' + (n-1));
```

Since `'x' + (n-1)` can't produce a string of JS that references `largeStr` no input can lead to `largeStr` being used but it is still pinned in memory.

---

To see the whole thing in action, play around with

```
 var f = (function () {
     var a = [,,,,,];
     return function (x) { return eval(x); };
   })();
 alert(f('a.length'));
```

Comment: @Bergi, I fixed that typo.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Okay let's consider what happens here;

```
var a = (function () { // `a` will be set to the return of this function
   var smallStr = 'x',
   largeStr = new Array(1000000).join('x'); 

   return function (n) { // which is another function; creating a closure
        eval('');
        return smallStr; 
   }; 
}());
```

The inner function needs to be able to access all variables from the outer function, meaning as long as a reference to it exists, variables from the outer function can't be garbage collected and hence continue consuming memory after it has finished invoking and therefore may result in "memory leaks".

If you're dealing with large data like this and you're finished with it, set it to `null`

Comment: A good explanation that should be self explanatory to anyone reading your answer interested in this.

Answer (score 0):

Let's rewrite the code just a little bit:

```
function makeClosure() { 
  var smallStr = 'x',
  largeStr = new Array(1000000).join('x'); 

   return function (n) { 
        eval(''); //maintains reference to largeStr
       return smallStr; 
  }; 
}

var a = makeClosure();
assert(a() === 'x');
```

`makeClosure` returns a function, hence `a` is a function. However, that function still executes in the scope where it was defined (that's the definition of a closure). If you were to do:

```
function makeEnumerator() {
  var count = 0;

  return function () {
    count++;
    return count;
  };
}

var enum = makeEnumerator();
assert(enum() === 1);
assert(enum() === 2);
```

`enum` still has access to `count`. Back to our case, the closure keeps a reference to `smallStr`, which stays in memory. `largeStr` is not retained and should be freed.

However, `eval` also executes in the current scope and might use `largeStr`. Because of that, the browser is forced to keep `largeStr` as well.

Long story short, don't use eval :)