# How to create memory leak and monitor memory usage in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I am trying to allocate memory in JavaScript to study memory leak/consumption using the code snippet below. However

```
performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
```

always shows the same number, 10000000 in my case. How come that number never changes despite dynamically creation of elements and attaching to DOM ?

I need a JavaScript snippet to create memory leak and monitor the usage using performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize  dynamically( or any other functions if exists).

I tried this code but performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize remains at 10000000:

```
<body>
    <p id="memory" style="position: fixed; top:10px; left:10px"></p>
<script>

    setInterval(() => {
        document.getElementById("memory").innerHTML = performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize
    }, 300);
     btn = [];
    let i = 0;
    setInterval(() => {
        for (let j = 0; j < 1000; j++) {
            ++i;
            let k=i;
            btn[k] = document.createElement("BUTTON");
            document.body.appendChild(btn[k]);
            btn[k].innerHTML = k;
            btn[k].addEventListener("click", function () {
                alert(k);
            });
        }
    }, 5000);
</script>
</body>
```

I already tired the example given in 2013 in this post, but this one no longer create memory leak either.

[How do I create a memory leak in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16256487/how-do-i-create-a-memory-leak-in-javascript)

Comment: My guess is that you are creating far too few elements to really affect to heap. 1000 dom elements and function objects closing over an integer, every 5 seconds? That's nothing. Try allocating large arrays filled with random values and store them in those buttons.

Comment: Did not help. Can you provide a working example ?

Answer (score 1):

**`performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize` does not update when the page is opened directly from the local file system.**

The image below shows that the exact same code copy-pasted from the question shows increasing memory usage when accessed at localhost:

[image: Proof]

Or, you can check for yourself: https://memory-leak.surge.sh/simple/ (You can also check the original code: https://memory-leak.surge.sh/ but your browser might  freeze up if left open for more than a few seconds.)

---

**How to host the HTML like I did above:**

The simplest option is to use dev tools like [Browsersync](https://www.browsersync.io/) or [Parcel](https://parceljs.org/). These tools will let you open files from your local file system as if they were hosted from a server with a URL like http://localhost:1234/ . (Because a temporary web server is started on your computer.)

Another option is to actually host the files on a server. There are many options to do this:

- [surge](https://surge.sh/) The tool I used for the examples above
- [Glitch](https://glitch.com/) (This one is cool because you can edit the files online and see changes right away)
- [Github pages](https://pages.github.com/)

*Note: results may vary based on browser/hardware. My environment:*

- Chrome Version 74.0.3729.131 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Windows 10

Comment: I need to try it at a remotely hosted version. Yes with youtube websites and many other website performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize keeps on increasing . I need a simple html.js file which does the same thing. Please provide a working example that can be hosted and yet increases the performance.memory.usedJSHeapSize

Comment: @Cgraphics: Here is the exact sample code hosted on a server; it will show memory use as expected: https://memory-leak.surge.sh/ My answer already explained how to get the same results without a server, but I will add more details about how to host locally. (Also, a much simple example should work, too.)